# How is a mobile app backend different from web application backend?

Tags: php, android, iphone, ruby-on-rails, backend

I'm a backend web developer. Never dealt with mobile in any way.
I'm being offered a job to build a backend for a mobile app, and thinking how should I prepare.

Could you outline principle similarities and differences between web app and mobile app backends?

Comment: Tips that are not direct answers to the question, are also very welcome in comments or answers,

Comment: most mobile backends are just APIS, so in a lot of cases they are the same, You are returning some sort of structured data (xml/json/etc) to the client. IN web app  javascript or browser renders it, mobile app, could also be browser. or dedicated app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real business logic and data structure is the same. The difference is how the functionality is exposed remotely.

A web site exposes this functionality over an HTTP protocol, this is simplest interface as pre defined UI (HTML pages) are just being distributed.

For a *custom* mobile application (not a browser) only the data is communicated, and native UI of device is used for presentation and interaction with that data. The data communication protocol/Interface is achieved by a web service.

- Business model -> server side controller (HTTP, HTTPS + AJAX, RPC etc) -> Web Browser (Web apps)
- Business model -> web service API (SOAP, REST etc)    -> Remote application (Desktop, Mobile apps)